# Implementing an Android gradient

Tags: android

I need to implement a gradient like the one shown below as Android gradient.

I would like to know what kind of gradient this is.

How can I build a gradient like this using Android drawables?

If I would like to know more about gradients like this, where can I find the resources?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Android background with gradient]

Comment: what does it have to do with gradient?

Comment: have you implemented anything so far?

Comment: I think this can be done with a 9-patch

Comment: Which **gradient** are you talking about?! I only see `a drawable with the right top and bottom corners set to be round`... or a **9 patch** (if we include the icon, as well).

Comment: Did you mean the rounded corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle" >
   <gradient 
     android:type="radial"
     android:centerX="50%" 
     android:centerY="50%" 
     android:startColor="#FF6CA941" 
     android:endColor="#FF008080" 
     android:gradientRadius="100"/>

    <corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple google would've got you your answer, but here you go:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient 
   android:type="linear" 
   android:angle="90" 
   android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
   android:endColor="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Set this as the background of your view, change the angle and colours to suit your needs.

Comment: this is the true gradient, but not the "gradient" the original poster meant :)